# BitmapFactory returns null with JUnit4

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, android-testing

I want to make local unit test that uses BitmapFactory.

When I make just new test class BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null. When I make test class that extends ActivityTestCase I get correct Bitmap object. This is test class that implements JUnit3 TestCase class.

But when I add @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) or @RunWith(JUnit4.class) my BitmapFactory returns null.

Is there any way to use JUnit4 unit tests in Android or not?

Comment: What is the size of the image file? Jpg? And its resolution? If the bitmap would become to big for available memory decodeFile will return null. Try with a very small image instead.

Comment: But it works with JUnit3 and in app...

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. It's a bit *%@#ed-up that if you want to read a bitmap you have to use instrumentation tests... I assume it's because the actual Bitmap class lives in android namespace/package.